# Auto remove getter-setters with lombok?

Tags: java, lombok, automated-refactoring, intellij-lombok-plugin

I have a project. I don't use Lombok. I use manually created getters and setters.

Now, I want to import Lombok. After I import, I will use for all entities.

Do I have to manually add `@Data` to all entities? And I have to remove all entities manually? Is not there another way to automatically convert those classes?

I could not find any questions like this:

https://www.google.com/search?q=lombok+automatic+remove+getter+site:stackoverflow.com&num=100&safe=off&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjXyqKT39bfAhXysYsKHWw4Ah0QrQIoBDAKegQIPxAM&biw=1497&bih=762

Answer (score 9):

In IntelliJ IDEA with Lombok plugin installed you should have this feature:

1. Navigate to the target class
2. menu Refactor | Lombok | Default @Data

This way you can refactor your classes one by one. I don't know if there're any existing batch refactoring tools for Lombok.

If you're interested in batch refactoring, please upvote [issue #574](https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/574) in Lombok plugin tracker. Or even contribute code to this project.

[image: refactor menu]
<sub>(source: [github.io](https://david-kerwick.github.io/assets/img/refactor-menu.png))</sub>

Comment: In Eclipse, you can select multiple classes in the sidebar and apply (some) operations en masse. Does IntelliJ have an option like that?

Comment: @chrylis at intellij,  when i select multiple classes from side bar, i have the option of only delombok enabled. What naxa shows is only for one class and from menu on the top. Eclipse has that option chrylis?

Comment: @chrylis Unfortunately, no. I tested it on my own project. When selecting a single class, I can run `Refactor | Lombok` or `Refactor | Delombok`. When selecting multiple classes, I can run `Refactor | Delombok`, but `Refactor | Lombok` is disabled. Tried in IntelliJ IDEA EAP 2018.3.3 with the latest Lombok plugin version.

Comment: @asdasasd I'd like to warn you that there's an open issue related to this Refactoring action - https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/555

Comment: UPDATE to the previous comment: issue #555 is closed as a duplicate of #688 https://github.com/mplushnikov/lombok-intellij-plugin/issues/688

Comment: The one-class-at-a-time limitation still exists and is unfortunate, but a clever teammate had a partial workaround: bind the desired refactoring operations to a keyboard shortcut. The person doing the refactoring would still need to navigate to each class individually, but it's at least a significant time saver.

Answer (score 1):

As an entity has on average maybe ten fields, there's a lot of text to be removed per class. Using standard formatting and a single line between methods, these 10 getters and ten setters mean `10 * 2 * 4 = 80` lines per class. All you have to add a single `@Data` annotation.

So I'd concentrate on the removal and write a simple regex recognizing trivial getters and setters. Adding the annotation to all modified  files afterwards is something I'd gladly do manually even for tens of entities. Forgetting one is no problem as it leads to obvious compile-time errors.

---

A trivial untested regex for trivial getters:

```
[ \t]+public [\\w<,> ]+ get[A-Z](\\w+)\\(\\)\\s*\\{\\s*return\\s+[a-z]\\1;\\s*\\}\\s*\n
```

No such regex can be perfect (mine breaks e.g., when arrays get returned or when you use non-standard formatting or naming; this is easily fixable, but other problems may come). Nonetheless, it can do its job.

My regex allows no comments in the method body, but I wouldn't call a commented getter trivial.

Comment: Sorry, i could not understand. How will i use this regex, with a script with javascript?

Comment: @asdasasd The regex has Java syntax, but this hardly matters. On Linux, I'd go for something like `perl -pi -e '[ \t]+public [\w<,> ]+ get[A-Z](\w+)\(\)\s*\{\s*return\s+[a-z]\1;\s*\}\s*\n' *.java`, but be careful as it overwrite the sources without asking (you are using version control, right!). I do similar things quite often.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in IntelliJ IDEA is using the shortcut Command + Shift + A and choose the refactor you want.

[see this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xk2Wi.png)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any IDE that can convert a whole project so I wrote a command line tool based on JavaParser: [lomboker](https://github.com/timo-a/lomboker).
So far it doesn't implement conversion to `@Data` but all the steps towards it: removing getters, setters, noargsconstructors, toString and EqualsAndHash and adding the respective annotations and their imports.
So it should be fairly easy to extend it to cover `@Data` as well.