# How to convert or apply Lombok on multiple classes or whole project

Tags: java, lombok

I need to use Lombok on the whole project. There are around 2400 classes. Is there any way to convert the multiple classes or entire project to Lombok annotated? Or it is like converting a class at a time is the only option.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example what you mean by "convert to Lombok"? Do you want to apply the exact same annotation to all of them? That can probably be automated with a nifty sed script (or equivalent). Or do you have to decide for each one what to do? Then automation won't be so easy.

Comment: There are a lot Java classes with getters and setters. So just want to apply @ Getter and @ Setter to all of them and also want to remove getters and setters (as of now) to reduce the lines of code. I was looking for some tool that can do such a thing - not sure whether it exists.

Comment: You might find this useful for your use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54055649/auto-remove-getter-setters-with-lombok

Comment: Thanks, @Mayank! That link is useful.